# progress bar chart in PHP

Tags: php

```
I am newbie in PHP, we are designing a simple quiz game in PHP.
```

I am trying to draw a horizontal progress bar in PHP.This is like a
rectangle of length (10*1)and divided into ten equal parts of size(1*1).
The quiz will have ten questions so the blocks will be filled with GREY colour
initially, when the user answers the questions it will turn green or red depending on
whether it's correct or not.

I couldn't find a open source library which could do this. Should I use PHP GD 
and draw it? or plz. suggest me any library to look out for

Thanks in advance.

Karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this easily with nested spans and divs. Here an example (untested, but should give the right idea) for 10 questions (should be easy to adapt for more or less question or make it dynamic):

Style:

```
#outer {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
}

.inner {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.inner.right {
    background-color: green;
}

.inner.wrong {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then you have to generate the spans accordingly:

```
<div id="outer">
<?php foreach($i=0;$i<10;$i++): ?>
    <span class="inner <?php echo (isAnswered($i)) ? 
                                     ((isAnswerRight($i)) ? 'right' : 'wrong') :
                                      ''; ?>"></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**Update:** [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/fxqDJ/) how the *generated* bar would look like.

Answer (score 0):

i would state the problem rather differently, if you need a progress bar, look for progress bar control implemented in css, you will find many.
you can also draw 10 div from html, styled using css like rectangular boxes, than add a class to the completed boxed with php to change their color.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width of a green/red/grey image.

10 width green, 10 width red and 80 with grey (10% green, 10% red, 80% grey/todo)

and with a bit of math you can change the size like you want to ...

Answer (score -1):

GD would be overkill, but sure, if you like to learn it.

I'd recommend a 10x1 table with either grey, green or red images inside.

regards,

/t

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data. a `<div>` or a `<span>` is what he should be looking for.

Comment: @user247245: Nothing personal, but especially because he is a newbie he should learn good Web practices. Tables have been misused long enough for these kind of things in the '90s, 10 years later it's really time to move on.